# System.ArgumentNullException in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Here's my DbContext. As you can see, the tables in database are named differently.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    public DataContext() : base("name=connString") { }

    public DbSet<Person> Personer;
}

[Table("Users")]
public class Person {
    [Column("UserID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column("UserFirstName")]
    public string Fornavn { get; set; }
    [Column("UserLastName")]
    public string Etternavn { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code that generates **`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source`**.

```
using (var db = new DataContext()) {
    var x = db.Personer.Count();
}
```

Comment: Where does `Personer` get initialized with a value?  The exception is telling you that it's `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personer must be a **property** not a field.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    public DataContext() : base("name=connString") { }

    public DbSet<Person> Personer { get; set; }
}
```